# Create sccm package with visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sccm

I'm very new to this topic so I do not know what really to google for.

My question: Is it possible to create an SCCM package from a Visual Studio Solution?

Best, Jeppen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's completely possible via WMI and WQL, here's Microsoft's own answer on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc146612.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Is my understanding correct: 1) Create the DLL, 2) Create a setup package 3) I package the .exe with the info from the link you provided